# mysql_fetch_assoc() gives an error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, associative-array

here is my code for the query in php:

```
$query3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM area_of_work") or die('Invalid query:'. mysql_error());

while($query3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3)){
    $flag = true;
    foreach($listOfUserAreas as $obj){
        if($obj->areaId == $query3['id']){
            $flag = false;
            break;
        }  
    }
    if($flag){
        $areaObj = new AreaInfo();
        $areaObj->areaId = $query3['id'];
        $areaObj->areaName = $query3['areaOfWork'];
        $areaObj->areaTableName = $query3['tableName'];
        array_push($listOfUnusedAreas, $areaObj);
    }
}
```

and i am getting this error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\job-skills\php\functions\user_unused_area_list.php on line 30
>   []

can't see something wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Did you connect to the database?

Comment: Mostly likely you have setup for `mysql_` to return array based reults within your connection

Comment: I'll echo @MadaraUchiha comment, and add that a basic conversion from `myslq_xx()` to `mysqli_xx()` is generally pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't use the same variables.. try like this

```
$query3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM area_of_work") or die('Invalid query:'. mysql_error());

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3)){
.....//Your code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Rename variable `$query3` to `$query` or something different from variable used in your `while loop`.

What you do on line: `while($query3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3))` is that you assign result of `mysql_fetch_assoc` to `$query3` (it's resource at this point) on the first iteration and on the second you pass `$query3` (an array already) to `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

**Note:** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
while($query3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3))
```

you are reassigning `$query3` with results of `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Should be something like this:

```
while($queryRes = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
$query3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM area_of_work") or die('Invalid query:'. mysql_error());
while ($query3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3)) {
```

It should be like this:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM area_of_work") or die('Invalid query:'. mysql_error());
while ($query3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first loop will work ok, but your second will fail:

```
while($query3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3)){
```

After the first loop has executed, you are assigning the result array to the resource, effectingly overwriting the resource.

Replace your line like this:

```
while($listOfUserAreas = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3)){
```

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
while($query3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3)){
```

You are using the same variable to read from, an to assign to.

You can fix it by replacing the aforementioned line, for this one:

```
$result = &$query3;
while($query3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

just changing those lines, the rest of your code will work.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to assign associate array to resource

```
while($query3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3))
```

which is wrong... try with different variable
    while($Result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3))

Answer (score 1):

```
while($query4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3)){
```

change name of fetch variable